# "Solr Spellchecker Issue: Suggesting 'kothi' Instead of 'kochi'"

Tags: solr, solrj, spell-checking, solrcloud, search-suggestion

I'm encountering an issue with the Solr spellchecker where it suggests "kothi" instead of the correct term "kochi." Despite having both terms in my index, the spellchecker is providing inaccurate suggestions.

**Code and Configuration :**

Below is the snippet of spell check configuration in solrConfig.xml file

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlvmn.png)

**Spellcheck Query and Response:**

http://localhost:8983/solr/ihcl/spell?spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true&spellcheck.dictionary=ihcl_spellchecker&spellcheck.q=kothi&spellcheck.collate=true

Response..:

```json
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":22},
  "command":"build",
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "kochi",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":1,
        "endOffset":6,
        "origFreq":1,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"kothi",
            "freq":1}]}],
    "correctlySpelled":false,
    "collations":[]}}
```

**Expected Outcome:**

```json
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":22},
  "command":"build",
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "kochi",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":1,
        "endOffset":6,
        "origFreq":1,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"kochi",
            "freq":1}]}],
    "correctlySpelled":false,
    "collations":[]}}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and expertise in advance. Thank you for any assistance you can provide .I truly value your support.

Comment: Why would it suggest `kochi` as an alternative spelling for `kochi` - it's already the same term? Generall you'll have to adjust `maxQueryFrequency` and `thresholdTokenFrequency` to match what you expect as the limits for what kind of words should be included in your spell check

Comment: Thank you for the response @MatsLindh. I have configured maxQueryFrequency value as 0.01 and thresholdTokenFrequency as 0.01.
This is working for my entire system correctly but only for these two records getting wrong. Any advice ?
Appreciate your time.

Comment: The values adjust what is considered a misspelling based on the frequency of tokens in your index; i.e. the token just being present isn't enough by itself, it also has to have a certain frequency to be included/considered correctly spelled.